# Operator precidence when function is made infix (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

Does making a function infix change it's precedence somehow? 
If I write

```
3 `take` reverse "123456789"
```

in ghci, it returns `987`, but if I write

```
take 3 reverse "123456789"
```

I get an error, presumably because it interprets this as `(take 3 reverse) "123456789"` and I can't pass reverse as an argument to take. Why does it not interpret the first statement this way? Isn't function application right associative?

Comment: Yes, the ``3 `take` reverse "123456789"`` is parsed as ``(3) `take` (reverse "123456789")``, so `take (3) (reverse "123456789")`. It is now an "operator", and operators have lower pecedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `` 3 `take` reverse "123456789" `` is parsed as `` (3) `take` (reverse "123456789") ``, so `take (3) (reverse "123456789")`.

Now `take` is thus an *operator*, and operators have lower pecedence. As is specified in the *Haskell report*:

> Any operator lacking a fixity declaration is **assumed to be `infixl 9`**.

So `take` has here fixity 9. If you thus would use this as:

```
'0' :  3 `take` reverse "1234567890"
```

it will be parsed as:

```
'0' : (3 `take` reverse "1234567890")
```

since `:` has fixity `infixr 5`.